# Install OpenNI2 on Windows without Primesense driver

Tags: windows, kinect, openni

I search a lot about installing OpenNI. But on every site explain installation with "Primesense" driver.

I tried OpenNI2.xx and then Primesense driver from https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect, But got this error :

`please install openni version 1.2.0.4 or higher`

what should I do to install this driver ?

Answer (score 1):

- First you should download and install [OpenNI 2.xx](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/)
- then download and install [NiTE](http://www.openni.org/files/nite/)
- download latest Microsoft Kinect for windows SDK and developor toolkit from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindowsdev/Downloads.aspx) and install SDK and toolkit in order.

Now you can enjoy your Kinect programming